# CSS:How to properly remove border using CSS when border-radius is used?

Tags: html, border, css

I have a div styled like so:
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwg1/xg25s/)

How can I remove all of the left hand side border, without the ugly curved radius?

Is it possible in CSS? Or is there a hack to do it? (or am I being too picky?)

Thanks Muchly,

Harley

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
border-radius: 0px 6px 6px 0px;
```

Comment: <blush><smacks-head> Oh yes! Why didn't I think of that? Sorted. Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

```
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
```

This will override any border radius css.

Comment: Why `0px` and not just `0`?

Comment: Note: `0` is unitless, so `px` is redundant.  Should just be `border-radius: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

TIL

```
border-top-left-radius: 8px 8px;
```

is a thing

Answer (score -3):

if you want to remove the border just use :
border: 0px;

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I didn't want to remove the whole border.

Comment: Not true, you can have border radius with no or transparent border.

Comment: Note: `0` is unitless, so `px` is redundant.  can just be `border: 0;`